# window.setInterval() does not load div content immeditly and disrupts ColdFusion sessionTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

Within my site I have a `<div>` that loads an RSS feed from `rss.cfm`.  The code below refreshes the RSS feed after 60 seconds as one would expect.

However, it does not initially load the `<div>` until after the first 60 seconds has elapsed.  It also causes the `sessionTimeout` in my `Application.cfc` to no longer log someone out, since I assume it is refreshing the `<div>` as it should. :D

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setInterval(function(){$('#rssHolder').load('/rss.cfm');}, 60000);
</script>
<div id="rssHolder">RSS Feeds loading...</div>
```

I read all of the documentation here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

As well as every reference of `window.setInterval` I could find here on StackOverflow.  I tested in Firefox 47, the latest Chrome release and Safari (did not check the version).  I am using jQuery 2.2.3 and Lucee 4.5, if that helps.

Any ideas?  Is `window.setInterval` the wrong method to use when dealing with both initial loading and ColdFusion `sessionTimeout`?

Comment: try putting the `<div>` before the `<script>` block.  And yes, if you're requesting a .cfm page every 60 seconds, that'll prevent your session timing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple fix for the page load problem. Create a function that wraps the `load()` and call that function both in interval timer and on page load

```
function loadFeed(){
 $('#rssHolder').load('/rss.cfm');
}
// interval timed loader
window.setInterval(loadFeed, 60000);
// initialize on page load
$(function(){
  loadFeed();
});
```

Not sure why session would time out though

Comment: Something amiss in the code you suggested.  Getting this: `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`.  I verified all the code is what you wrote and I did not notice any missing characters.  I tested on a page where it was the only code loaded.  Same error.

Comment: oops ...should be `window.setInterval(loadFeed, 60000);` ... bad copy paste edit. Fixed in answer

Comment: That got it.  Thank you! :D  Thinking it through, even though this does work, I am concerned that my `sessionTimeout` in CF will no longer work.  I may have to swap to a "click to refresh" option for that RSS feed.